# How to run older versions of node.js on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, nvm

I want to install `v0.8.6` of node along with `v0.10`.

1. How can I install NVM on windows
2. And use it to install older node

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`nvm` is suited for linux environments. It requires `HOME` variable to be set where it will put the different node versions. For windows there is [`nvmw`](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw).

Similarly an alternative to `nvm` is [`n`](https://github.com/visionmedia/n). For which the windows version is [`nodist`](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist).

See this useful [blog](http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2013/03/23/installing-and-switching-between-multiple-versions-of-node-js-n-vs-nvm/).

Comment: Thank you for the link to [Nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist), absolutely delightful

Answer (score 7):

I've just released a project called [NVM for Windows](http://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). It comes with an installer and super-easy commands.

[image]

Comment: Are those commands compatible with the Linux `nvm`? Else there's [`nvmw`](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw)

Comment: nvmw is barely maintained and doesn't support Git Bash, FYI

Comment: @CeesTimmerman -  NVM4W and nvm are different projects. Many basic commands are the same (nvm install, nvm use), but they are not a 1:1 match.

Comment: @DaveCariello - nvmw isn't "barely" maintained... it's full on deprecated/done :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a case like mine that I just want to remove the current version and install the older one, I just did it by running the node installer of the current version and select the remove button. Afterwards, I install the older version.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your current NodeJS version by using the command node -v. And changing your version can be done by using node version manager.

Use n, an extremely simple Node version manager that can be installed via npm.

```
npm install -g n   # Install n globally
n 8.16.0           # Install and use v8.16.0 OR any version you want
```